# Google Sheets Script while loop assistance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script in Google Sheets JavaScript that has a database of invoices. I'm trying to create a payment option where someone can select a vendor and make a bulk payment which then assigns the right amount to each invoice.

I've used a while loop and even though the payments work perfectly, the loop doesn't end and I don't know why.

```
function makePayment() {

  var dbsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('InvoiceDB');
  var dasheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  var casheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Calc');
  var amount = dasheet.getRange('I9').getValue();

  while (amount > 0) {
    var range = dbsheet.getRange("B1:B");
    var values = range.getValues();
    var invoiceNo = casheet.getRange('C1').getValue();

    var i = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
      if (values[y] == invoiceNo) {
        i.push(y);
      }
    }

    var Row = Number(i) + Number(range.getRow());

    var outstanding = dbsheet.getRange(Row, 9).getValue();
    var alreadyPaid = dbsheet.getRange(Row, 8).getValue();

    if (amount > outstanding) {
      dbsheet.getRange(Row, 8).setValue(alreadyPaid + outstanding);
      amount = amount - outstanding;
    } else {
      dbsheet.getRange(Row, 8).setValue(amount);
    }

    dasheet.getRange('C9').clearContent();
    dasheet.getRange('I9').clearContent();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `amount` is not greater than `outstanding`, `amount` is not modified. If `amount` is greater than `outstanding`, `amount` is decremented by `outstanding`. Since `outstanding` is always less than `amount` at this point, `amount` will never reach zero as a result of this and the loop will run infinitely because you never modify `amount` anywhere else. You either need to modify your condition, or the more likely solution is to add some modification of `amount` in your else clause so that `amount` can reach zero to end the loop.

Comment: Awesome, I knew I was doing something stupid but couldn't figure it out.